# Cannot retrieve connection status with PhoneGap 2.2.0

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

I was having the issue with 2.1.0 so I upgraded to 2.2.0 to make sure it wasn't down to a bug, however it's still not working.

I have the below code:

```
checkConnection: function() {

        alert(1);
        alert(navigator.connection.type);
        alert(2);

        var networkState = navigator.connection.type;

        if(networkState == 'Connection.UNKNOWN' || networkState == 'Connection.NONE') {
            return false;   
        } else {
            return true;    
        }
    }
```

The first alert fires and produces a 1, then after that it just dies. I've also tried navigator.network.connection.type which is an old reference, that doesn't work either. I'm now at a loss as to why it's not working, the other PhoneGap functions work just fine (such as GeoLocation).

For reference I'm on an iPhone 5 running iOS 6.0.1.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if the call to checkConnection is executed **after** the `deviceready` event.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
   console.log('Application online: ' + checkConnection());
}

function checkConnection() {
    var networkState = navigator.connection.type;

    if (networkState == Connection.UNKNOWN || networkState == Connection.NONE) {
        return false;   
    } else {
        return true;    
    }
}
```

Also you shouldn't compare with the string `'Connection.UNKNOWN'` but with the constant `Connection.UNKNOWN`. Without the single quotes.

Comment: Thanks, I've changed that, however that's not fixed the problem as the actual problem is retrieving the data from navigator.connection.type in the first place. That returns no value, when it calls the second alert() nothing happens as it can't retrieve that value.

Comment: @Ashley Are you sure the call to checkConnection is fired after the deviceready event? http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#deviceready

Comment: Now I feel silly, the function was being called too early! Cheers for picking that up, working a treat now!